# How do I run a Python script from a Photoshop script?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, photoshop, photoshop-script

Is it possible to run a run a Python script from a Photoshop script? For example: I've got two files: my_photoshop script.jsx which will run from Photoshop. And the seconds (python) my_python_script.py, which is called from with Photoshop by the first script.

**my_photoshop script.jsx**

```
// Call external file from Photoshop
call my_python_script.py; //pseudo code
```

**my_python_script.py**

```
# Python script
print ("Hello from Photoshop!")
```

I know it's possible to do something similar via a batch file...

**my_photoshop script.jsx**

```
// Call the external batch files
var myBat = new File("D:\\temp\\my_batch_file.bat");
alert(myBat);
myBat.execute();
```

**my_batch_file.bat**

```
echo Python...
"C:\path\to\python.exe" "c:\path\to\hello_world.py"
pause 100
```

However, but can it be done directly? Or is this as close as it's gonna get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `app.system`:

**my_script.jsx**

```js
app.system('python "D:/path/to/my_py.py" ' + app.version)
```

**my_py.py**:

```py
import sys
file = open("D:/path/to/py.log", "w")
file.write("Hello from Photoshop!\n")
file.write("PS version: " + str(sys.argv[1]))
file.close()
```

Result of **py.log**:

```text
Hello from Photoshop!
PS version: 20.0.10
```

p.s. note that `File.execute()` opens the file with a default app. If a user associated `.bat` files with a text editor, running `myBat.execute()` will open the file in the text editor.