# How can I run a photoshop script from python program?

Tags: javascript, python, photoshop, photoshop-script

I have a photoshop script that is used to count the number of pictures open in photoshop.

I want to execute this script from python.

Anyone, please help me.

Thank you

```js
// target photoshop

s2t = stringIDToTypeID;

var len = getPropertyDesc('application', p = 'numberOfDocuments').getInteger(s2t(p)),
    result = { v: 0, h: 0 };

for (var i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
    var ratio = getPropertyDesc('document', p = 'width', i).getDouble(s2t(p)) >= getPropertyDesc('document', p = 'height', i).getDouble(s2t(p));
    result[ratio ? 'h' : 'v']++
}

alert(result['v'] + 'v' + result['h'] + 'h')

function getPropertyDesc(target, property, idx) {
    target = s2t(target);
    (r = new ActionReference()).putProperty(s2t('property'), s2t(property));
    idx ? r.putIndex(target, idx) : r.putEnumerated(target, s2t('ordinal'), s2t('targetEnum'));
    return executeActionGet(r);
}
```

Comment: You can reduce that to 2 lines `var numDocs = documents.length; alert(numDocs);` Also are you running Windows? - if so you can call a batch file to run a python script.

Comment: Also [look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278094/how-do-i-run-a-python-script-from-a-photoshop-script)